# When 3-chloro-2,2-dimethylbutane reacts with water what are all of the products and followup questions

Tags: organic-chemistry

I would like to know what all the products are. I know that in the classical Sn1 reaction, we have 3,3-dimethyl-2-butanol. For the alkyl shift in a Sn1 reaction, we also have 2,3-dimethyl-1-butene and 2,3-dimethyl-2-butene.

I have other follow up questions: This is my first time learning about organic chemistry as a layperson. I have no access to university resources like equipment. How do chemists separate all of this in a lab setting?

Also, I'm curious about these alkyl shifts. How do you explain them? From what I understand when the carbon is attached to four other carbons and it is adjacent to a carbocation, we can have the methyl group move over to the adjacent carbocation. This is used when a hydride shift is not favorable due to higher order carbocations being more favorable.